# displaying user inputted numbers clockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML Page.User input a number say 8 . So numbers 1 to 8 should be displayed in circular or rounded format. (not inside a circle). how do this using jquery or css. Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: `circular or rounded format. ` ??

Comment: Not easily i'm afraid. SVG does allow you to render text along a path http://www.svgbasics.com/text2.html - although not supported in older browsers it's likely to be the least painful approach

Comment: @bipen google images "circular text", i assume he wants text around a circle

Comment: @xec... i think google cicular text will give him an answer.. why should he post it here... with no related codes ...